# payment request button in apple pay using stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, applepay

HI I am using iphone 6s for my payment.I want to pay by apple and website will be hosted on php supported server( https://afaq.mobitairportparking.co.uk/ ). when i am using windows or andriod it show google pay button and my payment successfully done. But when i am go to the apple devices the payment button not show.

- I have https.
- I also done verification in Apple pay web domain (.well-known).
- saved wallet in my iphone 6s (ios version 15).
- Using safari browser.

I am do each and everything my code working fine and also goole pay button show but in apple case button not shown.

Comment: I'm able to see the Apple Pay button at the URL you shared. Are you in a country that Apple Pay [supports](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207957)?

Comment: Apple Pay doesn't work in Pakistan I'm afraid, so the button won't be present for you.

Comment: sir can you please cheak one more time it shown or not. please https://afaq.mobitairportparking.co.uk/

Comment: Becasue when I talk with stripe developer the button not shown.

Comment: they also send me screen short the button not shown instead of button they show "payment method support not found. Check the pre-requisites above and ensure you are testing in a supported browser." this message I added in my code when the button not shown. so please can you one more time cheak that.

Comment: Yep, Apple Pay is present for me on macOS Safari.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help i am stuck but you help me thanks and one last thing can you tell me which country you acces this link so i can  open the vpn of same country.

Comment: The countries where Apple Pay is supported is listed here: https://support.apple.com/HT207957